# How bad does traffic get between East Hamilton and Oakville, Ontario?

Tags: ontario, traffic

Traveling from East Hamilton, Ontario to 3001 Hospital Gate in Oakville at different times of the day for a new job. What is the worst case scenario for traveling time at any time of the day, in either direction?

Comment: This is not really a travel question. Try Google maps and enter in the different times for departure. You may find different routes suggested depending on the time of day. There is also a toll road for part of the way (407) and you can decide whether that's worth it for you. If you're using it regularly you will want to get a transponder.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a travel question by the standards of this exchange, but a daily commute question. It is also very specific to your own needs, and as I cannot see any way to broaden it to a more general audience, I am voting to close.

Comment: @CGCampbell What standards are you referring to? See [this meta question](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3522/3221).

Comment: http://www.mto.gov.on.ca/english/traveller/trip/map.shtml?ll=43.696424,-79.459648&z=10 is what you need. Not useful to a visitor from elsewhere because they wouldn't recognize roads or know alternate routes

Comment: The 'at any time of the day' is a big problem. If you're talking public transportation that often has different has a different schedule during nights than during business hours. And what about weekends? Flagged as too broad. This question can only be answered if specifics are added.

Comment: Commuting how?  Bus?  Train?  Bicycle?  Car?  Helicopter?

Answer (score 1):

The worst case scenario is that **you do not reach your destination at all**.

In extreme cases, trains break down completely and travellers are completely stuck for hours.  Drivers may be stuck in cars for hours if a severe blizzard hits.  Cyclists and pedestrians may head back within minutes when everything is flooded.  If a tornado or earthquake destroys the one bridge that all modes of commuting need to use, you can't get there at all.

This applies to all travel by all modes, commuting or not.  The worst case scenario of a delay is a cancellation.  This might not be the answer you're looking for, but there isn't any answer that is more meaningful.

Comment: Having seen the normal peak hour traffic in the Hammilton area, I bet not much is needed to get a total block on the roads.

Comment: @Willeke Roads in the Greater Toronto Area defy logic and even mathematics.